# Why are my reports opening in html in Visual Studio 2019? And why am i not able to create a report under new project in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I tried to open a few reports, that I'd created earlier, on my VS 2019 and they open up in html, as attached in the screenshot. Also, I am unable to create a new report under project. I am not getting that option. I've attached screenshots for both. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Please advice

[image: Create Report option not available under new project][image: reports opening up as html code]

Comment: you ned to install SSDT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I did and I'm still unable to open or create reports